# body id font-face issue

Tags: css, font-face

I have "style.css" which is used by 2 pages of my website, the home page and the gallery page.

The problem is that on the home page @font-face is loaded but on the gallery page the @font-face isn't loaded.
Folder structure is "site">"gallery" (gallery is in the "site" folder) and the "style.css" is situated in the"site">css

Comment: Did you try to make absolute path? instead of "your-font.extension" something like "/your-font.extension" ?

Answer (score -1):

This seems pretty straight forward... put `../` infront of the css include

Comment: Are you using a header template? If not just change the css path in the gallery page and not the main page You can do lots of things like using absolute path `/css/style.css` or an if statement.